# How to create a site collection using C# remotely for sharepoint 2013 and 2016

Tags: site-collection

I would like to create for sharepoint on premise a site collection remotely.

However, the only piece of code I found on internet is for sharepoint online
https://gist.github.com/vman/9342224

```
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace CreateSiteCollections
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        //Open the Tenant Administration Context with the Tenant Admin Url
        using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite-admin.sharepoint.com/"))
        {
            //Authenticate with a Tenant Administrator
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

            var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);

            //Properties of the New SiteCollection
            var siteCreationProperties = new SiteCreationProperties();

            //New SiteCollection Url
            siteCreationProperties.Url = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/codesite";

            //Title of the Root Site
            siteCreationProperties.Title = "Site Created from Code";

            //Login name of Owner
            siteCreationProperties.Owner = "admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com";

            //Template of the Root Site. Using Team Site for now.
            siteCreationProperties.Template = "STS#0";

            //Storage Limit in MB
            siteCreationProperties.StorageMaximumLevel = 100;

            //UserCode Resource Points Allowed
            siteCreationProperties.UserCodeMaximumLevel = 50;

            //Create the SiteCollection
            SpoOperation spo = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);

            tenantContext.Load(tenant);

            //We will need the IsComplete property to check if the provisioning of the Site Collection is complete.
            tenantContext.Load(spo, i => i.IsComplete);

            tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //Check if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete.
            while (!spo.IsComplete)
            {
                //Wait for 30 seconds and then try again
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                spo.RefreshLoad();
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("SiteCollection Created.");

        }

    }
}
}
```

How can I tweak the above code to make it work on sharepoint 2013 et 2016

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above code you have mentioned is a client side code and it should work with SharePoint 2013 and 2016 on premise. Only thing here is instead on onlinecredential part you need to use Network credential.